# Views in my ListView's items steal ACTION_DOWN event from it

Tags: android, listview, ontouchlistener

I have `ListView` with complex items, that contain a few buttons and checkboxes (all of those buttons and checkboxes have their `onClickListener`'s). Every item in listView might be deleted by dragging it to the left/right side. To make items draggable I override `onTouchListener` for `ListView`.

My problem is that when I try to drag an item or to scroll the ListView up/down, I don't receive `ACTION_DOWN` event in `onTouch()` method, but only when I start the action from the area of any of those `Checkbox`'es and `Button`'s. So it looks like those elements steal my event. What I want to do, is to receive `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP` events in `onTouchListener` of ListView, and then when `ACTION_UP` occurs check out whether I'm scrolling/dragging (which I have no problem with), and if I'm not, perform click either for some Button/Checkbox (if `ACTION_DOWN` started from its area) or for an item (if `ACTION_DOWN` started from some area that doesn't belong to any of buttons/checkboxes).

Comment: What you are experiencing is completely normal. That's how touch events are processed. For example the button is consuming the touch events because it needs to handle clicks. There are a few ways to implement what you want to do, my recommendation is to use a `CoordinatorLayout` and the `SwipeDismissBehavior`.  Google for it,  you should find lots of resources explaining how to use it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely try that

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [SwipeMenuLib](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) library. It may be useful for you

Comment: Thanks, I will try it, but I still need to understand what's going on in my app anyway

Comment: You don't need some random library to implement this. Adding an uneccesary library is not the way to go.

Comment: I already commented on your question what my recommendation is.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, now I can see it